Uniqueness of differences of roots of polynomials over finite field
Let $f$ be a polynomial over a finite field $\mathbf{F}_p$ with $p \neq 2$. Let $R$ be the roots of $f$ in some extension field. I am interested in the multiset of differences $R - R = \{ r - s \mid r, s \in R \}$. Specifically, I am interested in the multiplicities of the elements in this multiset.
It's easy to see that in some cases, no element in $R - R$ appears with multiplicity 1 (i.e., no difference appears uniquely). For instance, this happens when $f$ is a square or when $f(x) = \prod_{a \in \mathbf{F}_p} (x - a)$.
Suppose now $f$ is irreducible. Can it still happen that no difference in $R - R$ appears uniquely (i.e., every element in $R - R$ has multiplicity greater than 1)?

Over $\mathbb F_p$, the polynomial $f(x) = x^p - x - 1$ is irreducible, and if $\alpha$ is a root, then the full set of roots is $R = \{\alpha + c : c \in \mathbb F_p\}$. In particular, the difference set of $R$ is the same as the difference set for $\mathbb F_p$.
